# How will add hr tag before first occurance of matched string?

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to convert docx to epub.   I need to find out first matched string. example

```
 <p class="ex">Example1</p>
 <p class="ex">Example2</p>
 <p class="ex">Example3</p>
```

I am trying:

```
 <p class="ex">([\s\S]*?)<\/p>
```

But i got all p tag.  How will i get first matched p tag?

And also add hr tag before that tag using regex.

I have google it for hr tag.  I have found that the below:

```
 "< hr />" tag is not recognized by pandoc
```

How will i add hr tag in epub conversion?

Any one assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when do you say a `p` tag is matched??

Comment: '<p class="ex">([\s\S]*?)<\/p>'.  The regex fetched entire p tag elements.

Comment: yeah but you are asking for `first matched p tag` in your question, what do you mean by that?

Comment: <p class="ex">Example1</p>. I need that tag only.  Example1 is the content. it is  dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just say that after the first match it needs to go through the input's end (`\0`):

`<p class="ex">([\s\S]*?)<\/p>[^\0]*\K`

Independently of global attribute setted or not, it will work.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/wD6lW2/1)

**Note:** I've used `\K` only to better illustration. Some languages don't support this feature. Anyways, as you are using `matching groups`, if the `\K` gives an error for you, you can just remove it. No problem by doing that.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** But your title suggests this regex:

`<p class="ex">[^\0]*`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/wD6lW2/4)

Comment: @Vanarajan. I've updated to satisfy your title request.